# Copy the result of a function to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, clipboard

Can someone tell me how to copy the result of a function to the clipboard?

After copying the result to the clipboard, I want to paste it after clearing the textarea.

```
function strReplace() {
    var myStr = document.getElementById("source").value;
    var newStr = myStr.replace(/&‌#‌1084‌;/g, "м")
                      .replace(/&‌quot‌;/g, '&quot;');
    if(document.getElementById("source").value == '') {
        alert("Textarea is empty!");
        return false;                    
    } else {
        // Insert modified string in paragraph
        document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = newStr;
        taErase();
        document.getElementById('button').focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you want to copy the value of the input with id source?

Answer (score 1):

Use this function and pass the value is to be copied as it's only argument.

```js
function copyText (copyText = null){
    let textArea = document.createElement("textarea")
    textArea.value = copyText
    textArea.style.position = "fixed"
    textArea.style.left = "-999999px"
    textArea.style.top = "-999999px"
    document.body.appendChild(textArea)
    textArea.focus()
    textArea.select()
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        document.execCommand('copy') ? res() : rej()
        textArea.remove()
        //alert('Text Copied!')
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### I did some changes in your code to simulate a functional example:

1. Auxiliary function `copyToClipboard` to copy element `value` to `clipboard`
2. Auxiliary function `getSource()` to generate a `source` if is `empty`
3. Auxiliary function `start()` trigger the process `manually`

When the page finish load, the code will:

- Check if `textarea` is empty and print in console (before was an alert)

Now press `start` button to init process and check if has something in `source` `input`

- If hasn't any text in `source` `input` or is empty, generate one

When has an text in `source` `input`:

- `replace` special chars
- `copy` to `clipboard`
- `copy` to `textarea`
- `focus` the **Click Me!** `button`

  - Added a `css` `background` to change the button color to see the `focus` *(Optional)*

> Some functions isn't necessary in your solution, just used it to build a functional example.

**Good pratices:**

1. **Choose one possibility:** In your code or use double quote `"` or single quote `'`
2. When post the problem try to post a functional exemple not just a part of code

##### Follow an example based on your question:

```js
function strReplace() {
  let source = document.getElementById("source");
  let myStr = source.value;
  let newStr = myStr.replace(/&‌#‌1084‌;/g, "м")
    .replace(/&‌quot‌;/g, "&quot;");
  if (myStr == "") {
    console.log("Textarea is empty!");
  } else {
    copyToClipboard(source);
    document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = newStr;
    document.getElementById("button").focus();
  }
}

function getSource() {
  let source = document.getElementById("source");
  if (!source.value) {
    source.value = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Page Title</title></head>" +
      "<body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>";
  }
}

function start() {
  getSource();
  strReplace();
}

function copyToClipboard(element) {
  element.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log("Text copied to clipboad:\n" + element.value);
}

strReplace();
```

```css
#button:focus {
  background: yellowgreen;
}

#source {
  min-width: 260px;
}

#myText {
  min-height: 130px;
  min-width: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="source" placeholder="Source">
  <button id="start" type="button" onclick="start()">Start</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <textarea id="myText"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="button" type="button" onclick="strReplace()">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```